# How would you interpret this question on a final?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Recently taken calculus $2$, and a question on the department final was written as such:

Graph and label the x-intercepts:
$4x^2 - 4y + 4z^2 + z = 4$

(I don't remember exactly what the equation was, but it doesn't matter other then being a $3$ variable equation.)

How would you answer?

Comment: What must be true about y and z when it intercepts the x axis?

Comment: that they equal 0?

Comment: What is your question? Your title is asking to "interpret a question", but your post is asking to answer a problem.

Comment: I guess not to figure out but what would you figure out? Would you graph the equation or would you graph the intercepts you calculated from the equation?

Comment: I guess plot might be a better word than graph as you are only talking about two points on the x axis. That's my interpretation of a not terribly well phrased problem anyway

Comment: I was deducted 5 points for not graphing the function. I took it as written, calculated the points and did not draw the function just the intercepts. My professor says I didn't graph it, so I don't get the points, but I did exactly what the question was asking. I am contemplating escalating the situation.

Comment: If you just drew the intercepts but didn't draw how the function behaves, then I can see why your professor docked you down for it. And why escalate the situation?

Comment: I didn't just draw the intercepts, I calculated them as well. Why escalate? I answered the question as written and I want my points - the final is worth a significant amount, the extra 5 points would mean jumping a full grade.

Comment: previous sample finals provided by the department had a different phraseology such as, graph the function (function) and calculate and label all intercepts

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but honestly, it seems like you want us to validate how you feel about losing some points and say that the professor is in the wrong for marking you down. If your concern is about getting more points, why not talk to your professor? But even doing that could make you come off as desperate for pity points. I understand you want a better grade and I've been in your position plenty of times, but it's better to talk things out with your professor than ask it to a bunch of strangers online.

Comment: it was more so not validate how I feel, but if my interpretation was correct. As someone previously mentioned, it is not best phrased question. I don't think my professor is necessarily wrong, I think they have their hands tied. I spoke with my professor once already and I they will not change it.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, you calculated what the $x$-intercepts were and drew where they would be on a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. But how does that show how the function behaves at every other point? I don't think you interpreted everything the question was asking for.

Comment: What you are getting it is what my original post was asking - if you had read the question on a final, how would you answer it, and by what you're saying, you would interpret it as graphing the equation.

Comment: You say you want your points, but what can you do about it? You said your professor won't change your grade. I would've drew how the function behaved and where exactly the function crossed the $x$-axis after calculating the $x$-intercepts. I'm not sure what's confusing about that. I would probably share more details in an answer, but in order to receive a good-quality answer, one has to show they struggled through the problem by providing as many details as possible so more experienced people can see and point out where one got stuck.

Comment: this may not be the best platform for my question, as I can do the graphing and the math, it was more so in how to interpret the question.

Comment: What is the student supposed to graph? $y=x^2-1$ assuming $z=0$ or a circle in the $x, z$ plane assuming $y=0$? Maybe some other slice through the surface or maybe a three dimensional sketch of the whole surface? I would guess the teacher has given a similar question before and just wants you to do that. They should be big enough to admit it is poorly worded if they want you to do something not explicitly in the question though.

Comment: This is a department final, my professor had nothing to do with actually putting the test together, head of calculus 2 does that.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems more appropriate for [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

What follows was originally posted as two consecutive comments, but after reading the other comments a bit more carefully it seems to me that your intended question is not really addressed. However, note that what you *actually* asked -- "How would you answer?" -- is not what I believe you intended to ask, namely whether the final exam question is ambiguous, along with giving your interpretation of the final exam question.

From a purely formal and technical standpoint, the question definitely involves what in linguistics is called [structural ambiguity](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22structural+ambiguity%22+linguistics). See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/498891/348829) and the 3rd paragraph in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/167516/49593). For an example right here, notice that if I had reversed the order of the [conjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunct) to the AND connective in the previous sentence, then two interpretations are possible. But in arguing for your interpretation of something like this, success will likely come down to whether your interpretation is reasonable in the context of the course -- past questions on previous tests, homework problems, worked examples in class, how many other students interpreted in your way, etc.

Comment: This seems to let the examiner off the hook for a lazy question. I have done this myself (making presumptions about how it might be answered). The onus is on the one asking the question to correct their own laziness, it has nothing to do with some collective unspoken contract within the course as to an expected answer.

Comment: @Paul: I pretty much agree with you, but my last sentence  what I think the OP will likely have to deal with if the issue is pursued, not how I would deal with it if the OP were my student nor how I think the teacher/examiner should handle it. My many comments to [this question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18963/745) may be of interest.

Comment: You are probably right

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this directly addresses my issue. I do agree that the question might be better suited for the english stack exchange, however I wanted to check with the math types if the interpretation of "graph" is always to graph the function however as mentioned, the question does leave room for ambiguity. I will argue for my interpretation using some of the methods you mentioned with my materials compiled from the semester. Thank you for your attention!